# Grabbing some data from a card-body div class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Good day.
My script is on progress and I need help or ideas to make it work properly. I am able to grab some data but its not really that readable and useful and your help and ideas are needed.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0"}
url = "https://bscscan.com/tx/0xb07b68f72f0b58e8cfb8c8e896736f49b13775ebda25301475d24554a601ff97#eventlog"

urlpage = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10, allow_redirects=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlpage.content, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find('div', class_='d-none d-md-inline-block u-label u-label--price rounded mt-1 ml-n1 text-nowrap').get_text()#.strip()
print ("Price: ", price)


data1 = soup.find('div', class_='card-body').get_text()#.strip()
print (data1)


data2 = soup.find('span', class_='btn btn-icon btn-soft-success rounded-circle').get_text()#.strip() 
print (data2)
```

Current Output:

```
Price:  
BNB: $422.35 (-3.05%) |  5 Gwei

Transaction Hash:
0xb07b68f72f0b58e8cfb8c8e896736f49b13775ebda25301475d24554a601ff97
Status:Success

Squeezed text (173 lines).
206
```

Wanted Output:

```
Price:  
BNB: $422.35 (-3.05%) |  5 Gwei

207 #-- latest data

Address: 0x81e0ef68e103ee65002d3cf766240ed1c070334d
Topics:  0 0x598cd56214a374d15f638dd04913e0288cd76c7833ee66b15cf55845d875a187
Data
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000061b23bae
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000979144b0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative which caters for always picking up latest transaction (if more transactions added). Because JavaScript doesn't run with `requests` content isn't as it appears on webpage. You need to target the element with id `myTabContent`.

I've attempted broadly to go with hopefully more stable selector lists and avoid some of the potentially less robust classes.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://bscscan.com/tx/0xb07b68f72f0b58e8cfb8c8e896736f49b13775ebda25301475d24554a601ff97#eventlog', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

#select price info
price = soup.select_one('#ethPrice').get_text(' ', strip = True)

# select latest event
last_transaction = soup.select_one('#myTabContent div.media:nth-last-child(2)')
latest_number = int(last_transaction.select_one('.btn-icon__inner').text)
address = last_transaction.select_one('a.text-break').text
topic = last_transaction.select_one('li > .text-break').text

print('Price:', price)
print('Latest number:', latest_number)
print('Address:', address)
print('Topics:', topic)
print('Data')
for data in last_transaction.select('[id^=chunk].text-break'):
    print(data.text)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Im playing around for some improvements on this approach

Comment: If you come across a future error with the above just drop a comment here.

Answer (score 1):

Actually,selecting all data according to requirement a little bit complex.I apply css selector,however, you also can apply find_all/find method.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0"}
url = "https://bscscan.com/tx/0xb07b68f72f0b58e8cfb8c8e896736f49b13775ebda25301475d24554a601ff97#eventlog"

urlpage = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10, allow_redirects=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlpage.content, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find('div', class_='d-none d-md-inline-block u-label u-label--price rounded mt-1 ml-n1 text-nowrap').get_text()#.strip()
print ("Price: ", price)


for card in soup.select('div.media')[1:2]:
    num=card.select_one('.mt-1.mr-3').text
    print(num)
    address=card.select_one('.col-md-10.mb-0 a').text
    print(address)
    topic=card.select_one('.text-monospace.text-break').text
    print(topic)
    data1=card.select_one('#chunk_2_4').text
    print(data1)

    data2=card.select_one('#chunk_2_5').text
    print(data2)
```

**Output:**

```
Price:  
BNB: $422.41 (-3.65%) |  5 Gwei

207
0x81e0ef68e103ee65002d3cf766240ed1c070334d
0x598cd56214a374d15f638dd04913e0288cd76c7833ee66b15cf55845d875a187
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000061b23bae
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000979144b0
```

It's working. The problem was data2=card.select_one`('#chunk_2_5')` not exist so you are getting None type error but everything is okey:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0"}
url = "https://bscscan.com/tx/0x173c462e910c95a67c119c61566330a835e4785221e247fada6d2279052519f1#eventlog"

urlpage = requests.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10, allow_redirects=False)
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlpage.content, 'html.parser')
price = soup.find('div', class_='d-none d-md-inline-block u-label u-label--price rounded mt-1 ml-n1 text-nowrap').get_text()#.strip()
print ("Price: ", price)


for card in soup.select('div.media')[1:2]:
    num=card.select_one('.mt-1.mr-3').text
    print(num)
    address=card.select_one('.col-md-10.mb-0 a').text
    print(address)
    topic=card.select_one('.text-monospace.text-break').text
    print(topic)
    data1=card.select_one('#chunk_2_4').text
    print(data1)
    # data2=card.select_one('#chunk_2_5').text
    # print(data2)
    #If you need all updated data
    #for all_data in card.select('[id^=chunk]'):
        #print(all_data.text)
```

**Output:**

```
Price:
BNB: $422.25 (-3.15%) |  5 Gwei

315
0x7ee058420e5937496f5a2096f04caa7721cf70cc
0x694af1cc8727cdd0afbdd53d9b87b69248bd490224e9dd090e788546506e076f
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000062e6b858
```